# Copy value N times in Excel

Tags: excel, copy, duplicates

I have simple list:

```
  A     B
item1   3
item2   2
item3   4
item4   1
```

Need to output:

```
  A
item1
item1
item1
item2
item2
item3
item3
item3
item3
item4
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is one way of doing it without VBA:

1. Insert a column to the left of A, so your current A and B columns are now B and C.
2. Put `1` in A1
3. Put `=A1+C1` in A2 and copy down to A5
4. Put an empty string in B5, by just entering a single quote (`'`) in the cell
5. Put a `1` in E1, a `2` in E2, and copy down as to get 1, 2, ..., 10
6. Put `=VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$B$5,2)` in F1 and copy down.

It should look like this:

```
| A  | B     | C | D | E  | F     |
|----|-------|---|---|----|-------|
| 1  | item1 | 3 |   | 1  | item1 |
| 4  | item2 | 2 |   | 2  | item1 |
| 6  | item3 | 4 |   | 3  | item1 |
| 10 | item4 | 1 |   | 4  | item2 |
| 11 |       |   |   | 5  | item2 |
|    |       |   |   | 6  | item3 |
|    |       |   |   | 7  | item3 |
|    |       |   |   | 8  | item3 |
|    |       |   |   | 9  | item3 |
|    |       |   |   | 10 | item4 |
```

Comment: ... and then possibly copy by values.

Comment: (Visual Basic for Application gives static results)

Comment: @MUYBelgium, that depends. If you want to keep things dynamic, then no. The OP was not specific in that regard, so I'll leave it as-is

Comment: @user1581199  You should rather use this trick because it allows you to keep it dynamic.  A visual basic routine using a for each loop will not be dynamic.  In general, it is always better to use 'normal', 'graphical' or 'through menu/formulas' way of doing of Excel rather than using VBA, which is not as simple as it appears and cannot be ported to other office suites.

Comment: Instead of VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$B$5,2), you can use VLOOKUP(ROW(F1),$A$1:$B$5,2) and forget about the E column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the VBA solution. I don't quite understand the comment that VBA won't be dynamic. It's as dynamic as you make it, just like a formula. Note that this macro will **erase all data on Sheet1** and **replace it with the new output**. If you want the desired output on a different sheet, then change the reference to `Sheet2` or what have you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultiCopy()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim currRow As Long
Dim nCopy As Long
Dim item As String

'store cell values in array
arr = Sheet1.UsedRange
currRow = 2

'remove all values
Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
Sheet1.Range("A1") = "A"

For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
    item = arr(i, 1)
    nCopy = arr(i, 2) - 1
    If nCopy > -1 Then
        Sheet1.Range("A" & currRow & ":A" & (currRow + nCopy)).Value = item
        currRow = currRow + nCopy + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I also disagree with the comment @MUYBelgium made about VBA being non-dynamic. However, to prove your case, should you not have writen a function rather than a sub? Then the function can be called as part of an array formula and everything will be dynamic.

Comment: @flodel Perhaps I should have, but I'm too much of a novice to resolve the complications that would create. This VBA approach seemed easier. With a function, the user would have to manually select a range the same size as the expected output, or the function would have to return values in such a way that you would manually fill the array formula until cells stop receiving values (end of list - I guess you could indicate it with `#VALUE` or `-` etc.). This seemed more efficient from an end-user POV and the logic is simpler to follow. It could be a bit more generic, though. :)