# Excel copy cell values X times with increasing numbers in the end

Tags: excel, vba

I have a similar task as in there:
[Copy value N times in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841213/copy-value-n-times-in-excel)

But mine is a bit more complex.

So, I have this kind of sheet:

```
    A         B
  dog-1.txt   3
  cat-1.txt   2
  rat-1.txt   4
  cow-1.txt   1
```

The final result needs to be the following:

```
    A
  dog-1.txt
  dog-2.txt
  dog-3.txt
  cat-1.txt
  cat-2.txt
  rat-1.txt
  rat-2.txt
  rat-3.txt
  rat-4.txt
  cow-1.txt
```

As you see it doesn't only multiply the cell content X times taken from column B, but it also increases the number in file name the same number of times with 1 step increase.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (***tried and tested***):

```
Sub Extend()

    Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet, NewCell As Range
    Dim Dict As Object, NewStr As String

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set Rng = WS.Range("A1:A5") 'Modify as necessary.
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Not Dict.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            Dict.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next Cell

    Set NewCell = WS.Range("C1") 'Modify as necessary.
    For Each Key In Dict
        For Iter = 1 To CLng(Dict(Key))
            NewStr = "-" & Iter & ".txt"
            NewStr = Mid(Key, 1, InStrRev(Key, "-") - 1) & NewStr
            NewCell.Value = NewStr
            Set NewCell = NewCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Next Iter
    Next Key

End Sub
```

***Screenshot (after running):***

[image]

The logic here is to get each name from the first column, store it as a dictionary key, then get the value beside it and store that that as the key-value. We then iterate inside each of the dictionary's keys, where we use the key-value as the upperbound of the iteration. During each iteration, we modify the string to change its number to the "current digit" of the iteration.

We choose `C1` as the initial target cell. Every iteration, we offset it one (1) row below to accommodate the new/next iteration.

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Tested , is this what u wanted :) ? (Working fine in my system)

```
Sub teststs()
Dim erange As Range
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim rnt As Integer
Dim str As String
Dim lrow2 As Integer


With ActiveSheet
lrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  ' finding the last row

For Each erange In .Range("A1:A" & lrow) ' loop though each each cell in the A column

cnt = erange.Offset(0, 1).Value
rnt = Mid(erange.Value, InStr(erange.Value, "-") + 1, 1)
For i = 1 To cnt 'Looping to cnt times

With Sheets("Sheet2")
lrow2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

str = Replace(erange.Value, rnt, i, InStr(erange.Value, "-") + 1)
.Range("A" & lrow2).Value = Left(erange.Value, InStr(erange.Value, "-")) & str
End With
Next i

Next erange
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1: For correcting the error on the `Replace`. Obviously, `Replace` is much more error-prone than other string manipulation techniques.