# How to get median from dynamically picked numbers?

Tags: median, libreoffice-calc

I can't find in google answer to my problem. Hope you guys will help me!

This is my sheet:

[image]

This is shooting result. You can see here columns with points from 1 to 10 and number of shoots to each region of target.

And now I have to get median to get mean value of one shoot. In this example it should be something like this:

=MEDIAN(10;10;10;9;9;9;9;9;8;8)

Because we've 3x10, 5x9 and 2x8 shoots. How can I do that automatically?

Hope you guys understand my problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy value N times in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841213/copy-value-n-times-in-excel)

Comment: take a look on the answers for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841213/copy-value-n-times-in-excel -- I think it will do the trick

Comment: So you have shot 10 times and reached 91 points in sum. So in my opinion the mean per shot is 91/10 = 9.1. So `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:K2,B3:K3)/SUM(B3:K3)`. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `10` is in B2 and you really want the median rather than the mean then not fully automatically but perhaps a help, in say L3:

```
=REPT(B2&";",B3)&REPT(C2&";",C3)&REPT(D2&";",D3)&REPT(E2&";",E3)&REPT(F2&";",F3)&REPT(G2&";",G3)&REPT(H2&";",H3)&REPT(I2&";",I3)&REPT(J2&";",J3)&REPT(K2&";",K3)
```

Then, to avoid repeating the above, in say L4:

```
 =LEFT(L3,LEN(L3)-1)
```

Paste the above as text into say L5 and, in the formula bar, wrap with `=MEDIAN(` and `)`.