# Research data analysis in Excel: Median of x times column value

Tags: excel, median

I need to analyze empirical research data.

```
Question      Fully agree (1)   Agree (2)    Neither(3)      Disagree (4)
```

```
Q1                 7               3             2             5   
Q2                 10              7             0             0  
Q3                 4               3             3             7  
Q4                 15              0             2             0
```

So for Question Q1, 7 people fully agree, 4 agree, etc.

I have to calculate the median for all questions. The result should look like this:

```
Question      Fully agree (1)   Agree (2)    Neither(3)      Disagree (4)    Median
```

```
Q1                 7               3             2             5               2

Q2                 10               7             0             0               1
```

For Question Q1, 7 people answered with "fully agree", 3 with "agree", 2 with "Neither" and 5 with "Disagree". I want to calculate the Median of the Answers for Question Q1: "Fully agree" is equivalent to the number 1, "Agee" to 2, Neither to 3 and Disagree to 4. So all answers for Q1 would be: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4. The Median is: 2

For Q2 it is: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2. The median is 1

Usually I don't work with Excel, so all functions are new to me. I have now tried different solutions for several hours: e.g. VLOOKUP ([Copy value N times in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841213/copy-value-n-times-in-excel))

Unfortunately I was not successful so far; maybe there is a very simple solution to calculate the median :). Hopefully a solution that is not based on VPA, as I have even less experience here.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It would also help if you were to include the answers for each question in your sample data, just so there can be no confusion over what you want, and so that it's easier for answerers to check their results.

Comment: The answers should be 2, 1, 3, 1 right?

Comment: If there is a tie for median between say 2 and 3, what do you want to return? 2? 3? 2.5? Or doesn't it really matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fun way of doing it with a pretty simple formula:

```
=MID(REPT(1,B3)&REPT(2,C3)&REPT(3,D3)&REPT(4,E3),SUM(B3:E3)/2,1)
```

[image]

See the Explanation column,, that shows how I'm building a string consisting of all the values with `REPT(1,B3)&REPT(2,C3)&REPT(3,D3)&REPT(4,E3)`. All I have to do then is extract the middle vallue, which is what the `MID(Explanation,Number of entries / 2, 1)`

If you have an even number of answers, and want to split the difference should say the middle point be between the values of 2 and 3, you can use this array-entered formula:
`=AVERAGE(VALUE(MID(REPT(1,B3)&REPT(2,C3)&REPT(3,D3)&REPT(4,E3),SUM(B3:E3)/2+ISEVEN(SUM(B3:E3))*{0,1},1)))`

Comment: haha - crazy .. It's even easier and I have even less idea what exactly lies behind this formula. I would like to accept both answers. Thank you again

Comment: Shouldn't *'If there is an odd number of results, the median is the middle number.
If there is an even number of results, the median will be the mean of the two central numbers.'* be considered?

Comment: True...I'll have to add an IF and a VALUE statement to handle that. Will do later...wife is glaring at me.

Comment: @Jeeped Formula updated to handle even split, using a simple hardcoded array to return two entries (one offset by one in the event of a split) which is then processed by AVERAGE

Answer (score 2):

I chose to repeat your single digit scores into a string and pluck out the median with MID and some maths.

```
=IF(ISODD(SUM(B2:E2)),--MID(REPT(B$1,B2)&REPT(C$1,C2)&REPT(D$1,D2)&REPT(E$1,E2),CEILING.MATH(SUM(B2:E2)/2),1), AVERAGE(--MID(REPT(B$1,B2)&REPT(C$1,C2)&REPT(D$1,D2)&REPT(E$1,E2), SUM(B2:E2)/2,1), --MID(REPT(B$1,B2)&REPT(C$1,C2)&REPT(D$1,D2)&REPT(E$1,E2), SUM(B2:E2)/2+1,1)))
```

I used custom number formatting so that the scores in B1:E1 could remain real numbers but you could hard-code the numbers into the REPT functions if you prefer true text labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

F3: `=SUM(B3:E3)/2`

G3: `=SUM($B3:B3)`

H3: `=SUM($B3:C3)`

I3: `=SUM($B3:D3)`

J3: `=SUM($B3:E3)`

K3: `=IFERROR(MATCH(F3,G3:J3,1)+1,1)`

Comment: Thank you :) - I just checked the Media for e.g. Q1; it should be actually 2, not 1?!

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. And I'm working on an array version that doesn't need helper columns. Please hold caller...

Comment: I don't know how, but it calculates the right result. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

simply do:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3,4},B2:E2)/SUM(B2:E2)
```

:)

**EDIT**:
ups... that's "mean"

best solution for median i was able to create was:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B2)),1),IF(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,C2)),2),IF(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,D2)),3),IF(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,E2)),4))}
```

but it will count "0" as 1 :(

or

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(B3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,B3)),1)),IF(C3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,C3)),2)),IF(D3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,D3)),3)),IF(E3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,E3)),4)))}
```

but that will count every 0 as a 0 :(

OK... this should work:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(B3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,B3)),1),{0,5}),IF(C3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,C3)),2),{0,5}),IF(D3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,D3)),3),{0,5}),IF(E3,IF(ROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,E3)),4),{0,5}))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I get the result 2.29 --> Is it correct then if I just round up or down?

Comment: Actually, your proposed method calculates the mean and not the median. Right?

Comment: On a re-read of the OP's post, I'm thinking the answers need to be 2, 1, 3, 1 for this sample set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Since I often have the answer 0, I guess I have to enter all answers manually and calculate norman with MEAN.

Comment: @Math_reald Not necessarily. But again, can you amend your question to show the answers you expect.

Comment: @Math_reald the last one should do the trick... only fails if there are 4 0's