# Research data analysis in Excel: Column indexing

Tags: excel, indexing

I need to analyse empirical research data:

Given the following data:

[image]

The explanation: 5 people answered Question 1 with "entirely agree", which is equivalent to a score of 7. Zero people answered Question 1 with "entirely disagree", which would be a score of 0.

I want now to calculate the number of responses strictly less than the Median and the number of answers equal to the Median.

The result should look like this (the Median is given thanks to [Research data analysis in Excel: Median of x times column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457149/research-data-analysis-in-excel-median-of-x-times-column-value/51458010#51458010))

[image]

I tried with the functions =INDIRECT and =INDEX; without success.
Would be great, if someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIF:

Below:

```
=SUMIF($B$6:$H$6,"<" & I2,B2:H2)
```

Equal

```
=SUMIF($B$6:$H$6,"=" & I2,B2:H2)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I don't quite understand the second formula, but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A working, but not a better solution is to sum up the row conditionally:

[image]

the highlighted cell has this formula:

```
=IF(B6<I2,B2,0)+IF(C6<I2,C2,0)+IF(D6<I2,D2,0)+IF(E6<I2,E2,0)+IF(F6<I2,F2,0)+IF(G6<I2,G2,0)+IF(H6<I2,H2,0)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer: J2 should be 11 since the Median is 6 (score 6) and below is score 5 (10 answers),4 (1 answer) ,3(0 answers),2 (answesr) and 1 (0 answers)

Comment: @Math_reald I edited the answer, sorry I was confused, I thought the median is to be compared with the total of people who answered not with the score :)